# app crashes when accessing plist on ipad, but not in simulator

Tags: xcode, plist

In my app im using 3 different plists. 2 of them work fine, but when i try to access the third, it crashes on the ipad. Works fine in the simulator.

here is the code i use to access my plists

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
self.path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"profiles.plist"];
self.path2 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"services.plist"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"profiles" ofType:@"plist"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:path error:&error];
}

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path2])
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"services" ofType:@"plist"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:path2 error:&error];
}
```

When i go to write to it

```
NSString *pName = profileName;
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

NSMutableArray *profilesArr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]autorelease];
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init ]autorelease] ;

NSMutableArray *tempArr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];

for (int i = 0; i < [self.visibleLegend count]; i++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *legendDict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]autorelease];
    AGSLayerDefinition *layer = [self.visibleLegend objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *layerDef = layer.definition;
    NSString *layerId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", layer.layerId];
    NSLog(@"save ID %@, save DEF %@", layerId, layerDef);

    [legendDict setObject:layerId forKey:@"layerID"];
    [legendDict setObject:layerDef forKey:@"layerDEF"];

    [tempArr addObject:legendDict];
}

NSString *dynamicURL = [self findServiceName:[self.dynamicLayer.URL absoluteString]];
NSString *tiledURL = [self findServiceName:[self.tiledLayer.URL absoluteString]];

[tempDict setObject:pName forKey:@"profileName"];
[tempDict setObject:dynamicURL forKey:@"dynamicLayer"];
[tempDict setObject:tiledURL forKey:@"backgroundLayer"];
[tempDict setObject:tempArr forKey:@"visibleLegend"];

[profilesArr addObject:tempDict];
if ([profilesArr containsObject:tempDict])
    NSLog(@"added");
if ([profilesArr writeToFile:path atomically:NO])
    NSLog(@"new saved");
```

the plist stored in path is the only one that seems to crash on the iPad. i cant figure out whats wrong. the debug just shows a bad access to an assembly language line of code.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by turning on arc mode and removing all of the autorelease commands on my objects. It seems that my plist array was getting dealloced by itself and causing problems on the ipad.